# mongodb schema design, should I create separate collection to store tag

Tags: mongodb

I am designing schema for mongodb and I need advice on one design issue. One of my collection (A) has a field (F_1) which can have value from a list of predefined values (item may insert/delete later in this list). My issue is should I use just text field to store F_1 or should I use collection to store F_1 with repopulated list and use reference on A. Please advice or point me to documentation.

Comment: It's a bit hard to know what is your use case, but if your `F_1` field does not grow too much (<16MB), you do not need to store it in a separate collection. But if your `F_1` will grow, can be duplicated, interact with other `F_1`, you should create separate collection and link with `A` collection

Comment: why are you concerned about this field F1?  are you saying it is going to be a very large array or sub doc?...your description doesn't seem to mean that.... generally you want to avoid relational link docs

Comment: I am trying to find the good design based on suggestions. Usually F1 is an array of string no more than 10 elements. Actually, UI will have them percolated in list for user to select.